# How to get a Teradata SQL Timestamp without milliseconds

Tags: teradata

How can can I create a Teradata SQL Timestamp without milliseconds in a SELECT statement?

For instance, "2020-06-23 14:39:11".

The format should be "YYYY-MM-DDBHH:MI:SS".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Teradata 16 you can use the code below.

Timestamp without milliseconds

```
SELECT Current_Timestamp(0) AS DATE_TIME;
```

Timestamp with milliseconds

```
SELECT Current_Timestamp AS DATE_TIME_MS;
```

Comment: `SELECT Current_Timestamp(0)` strips off subseconds

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but if you've got an existing field stored as timestamp(6) (with milliseconds), you can cast it as timestamp(0). It's kind of funky though, you can't just directly cast it. You have to cast it as a string, substring it to lose the millis, then you cast it back as timestamp(0).

```
cast (substring(cast(<ts_column> as varchar(26)) from 1 for 19) as timestamp(0))
```